# want to display duplicate ranks selected along with exactly which ranks are duplicated using javascript/ jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Here we added the logic to display which ranks are duplicated but I also want to display exactly which rank is duplicated. Ranks are from 0 to 18.

```
function validate(sdd_ejrp_form) 
    {
        var duplicateRanksDetected = false;
        var validate_rank_str = ",";
        jq("\[data-dom-id=gsc-containers\]").find("\[data-dom-id=gsc-container\]").each(function (index)
        {     var jqThis = jq(this);
              var gsc_uri = jqThis.attr("data-gsc-data-gsc-uri");
              var prof_lvl_rank = jqThis.find("select\[name='prof-lvl-rank'\]").val();
              jqThis.find("\[data-dom-id=proficiency-level\]").each(function (index2)
             {
               var btn = jq(this);
               if (btn.hasClass("active")) 
              {
             if (validate_rank_str.indexOf("," + prof_lvl_rank + ",") != -1) 
                     {
                        duplicateRanksDetected = true;
                        return false;
                     } else 
                        {
                            validate_rank_str += prof_lvl_rank + ",";
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            if (duplicateRanksDetected == true)
            { 
               // here I want to display exactly which rank is duplicated
               alert("Duplicate ranks detected!");
               return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: java is to javascript as car is to carpet - unrelated - which do you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy as 3 modifications:

```
function validate(sdd_ejrp_form) {

  var duplicateRanksDetected = []; //create an array here

  var validate_rank_str = ",";
  jq("\[data-dom-id=gsc-containers\]").find("\[data-dom-id=gsc-container\]").each(function(index) {
    var jqThis = jq(this);
    var gsc_uri = jqThis.attr("data-gsc-data-gsc-uri");
    var prof_lvl_rank = jqThis.find("select\[name='prof-lvl-rank'\]").val();
    jqThis.find("\[data-dom-id=proficiency-level\]").each(function(index2) {
      var btn = jq(this);
      if (btn.hasClass("active")) {
        if (validate_rank_str.indexOf("," + prof_lvl_rank + ",") != -1) {

          duplicateRanksDetected.push(prof_lvl_rank); // fill the array here

          return false;
        } else {
          validate_rank_str += prof_lvl_rank + ",";
        }
      }
    });
  });

  if (duplicateRanksDetected.length > 0) {
    // here I want to display exactly which rank is duplicated
    alert(
      "Duplicate ranks detected: " +
      duplicateRanksDetected.join(', ') // display the result here
    );
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kosh Very need ur help for one more problem... In the above problem we detected the duplicate rank. I also want to sort the GSC ranks.. There are 1 to 18 ranks which we r assigning randomly to the competencies after submitting those ranks On the confluence page I want to display those ranks in sorted manner like the compentency given 1 rank displayed first & then 2 to 18.

Comment: 1 - Communication (Basic)
18 - Computational Thinking (Intermediate)
3 - Creative Thinking (Advanced)
2 - Decision Making (Basic)
4 - Developing People (Intermediate)
9 - Digital Literacy (Advanced)
17 - Interpersonal Skills (Basic)
11 - Leadership (Intermediate)
15 - Lifelong Learning (Advanced)
12 - Problem Solving (Basic)
16 - Resource Management (Intermediate)
7 - Sense Making (Advanced)
13 - Teamwork (Basic)
5 - Transdisciplinary Thinking (Intermediate)
10 - Virtual Collaboration (Advanced)

Comment: I want to display it in order like                                                                                        1. Communication(Basic)                                                                               2. Decision Making(Basic) and so on.... till 18

Comment: I need ur help in this problem @Kosh Very

Comment: You got my answer 20 days ago. If it's correct why did not you accept it? If it's not correct why are you asking for more help now?

Comment: Sorry I was busy In something else hence not got chance to test it.. On monday I have tested it.. Its working.. Thanku.. Plz help me for this question now.. plz

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
AJS.toInit(function() {
#if($permissionHelper.canEdit($user, $content))
 ## You have Edit Permission for this Page
AJS.$('#navigation .ajs-menu-bar > li:nth-child(1)').after('<li class="ajs-button normal"><a id="editJobProfilePageLink" href="'+contextPath+'/taxonomy/profiles/render-edit-job-role-profile-page-action.action?pageId=$paramPageId" rel="nofollow" class="aui-button aui-button-subtle edit" accesskey="e" title="Edit (e)"><span><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-edit"></span><u>E</u>dit</span></a></li>');
#end

});
</script>

Comment: we r using this JS function in macro "jr_profile_page_res_macro"

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand what your next problem is. If you want to display `duplicateRanksDetected` sorted, you can use `sort` function.

Comment: I dont want to sort duplicate ranks detected, I want to sort the proficiency level ranks which we r displaying                                                                 1 - Communication (Basic)                                                                    
18 - Computational Thinking (Intermediate)                                                                                                     
2 - Decision Making (Basic)  (From 1 to 18)

Comment: In the below function "prof_lvl_rank"  is there I want to sort that (currently it is displaying randomly as we selected)   but I want to sort it in ascending order from 1 to 18

Comment: I think it would be better if you create another separate question with a code snippet for that.